# Insert the word "last" into the "visited" field of user profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Suppose a user profile's "visited" field has this value:

> **visited** 200 days, 4 consecutive

The "4 consecutive" part means that visits were made during the last four consecutive days (as we have come to experience), but at first glance it looks like only four of the 200 days were consecutive.

It might be better to display the "visited" field with the word "last" inserted, like this:

> **visited** 200 days, last 4 consecutive